# Dynamic size of left and right Div's according to content

Tags: html, css

I am building a web page which has 3 DIV inside the main content left,right,right2.Here is a rough design:

```
<div id="content"> 
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div  id="right"></div>
    <div id="right2"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for it:

```
#content {
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    min-height:700px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color:#6495ed;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    min-height:700px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color:#6495ed;
    overflow:auto
}
#right2 {
    float: right;
    min-height:700px;
    width: 450px;
    background-color:#FFFFF0;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The issue is the 3 div's left,right and right2 do not fit according to the content size.Like if the main context increases,they stick to 700px height.If I give height:auto then the DIV aren't visible.
I have attached two images to help understand better:[image: SNIP1]
[image: SNIP2]
So basically I want to make the size dynamic of the left and right DIV's too,but cannot find a way to do it.Thank you for any responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
display:table-cell;
height:auto;
```

Nowadays I see this problem often

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzjz575a/)

Comment: Sure,I will test it and revert back

Answer (score 1):

Please user below div structure and its css.

```
 <div id="content" style="float: left; height: 700px; width: 100%;"> 
      <div class="content_blk">first block content</div>
      <div class="content_blk">second block content</div>
      <div class="content_blk">third block content</div>
    </div>

css
#content{
  float: left;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content_blk {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```